# image rotated to 90 degree when sending to server

Tags: android

I implemented a function that captures an image and send it to server.

If I take a picture with portrait mode and then send it to the sever, the picture always rotates to 90 degree left
But, if I repeat this with horizontal mode, everything works fine.

So, I came up with an idea
I turned the picture into a bitmap object and got width and height. 
What I tired to do was to rotate picture to 90 degree right before sending to server (when I tried with portrait mode)
However, it never worked (the picture with portrait mode also has more pixels on width......)

Can anyone give some hint for me??

```
private void call_camera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
}
```

this is for calling camera function.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA){

        imageUri = data.getData();
        Log.d("메시지", "uri = "+imageUri);


        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();
        absolutePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
    }
}
```

I made a File object by using absolutePath
and then sent it to server.

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        int maxBufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {

        DataOutputStream dataWrite = new     DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            dataWrite.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();

        wr.writeBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        wr.flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following method

```
private Bitmap fixOrientation(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ExifInterface ei = null;
    Bitmap selectedBitmap;
    try {
        ei = new ExifInterface(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            selectedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            selectedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            selectedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            selectedBitmap = bitmap;
            break;
        default:
            selectedBitmap = bitmap;
    }
return selectedBitmap;
}
```